# Vetor dentro de matriz?

Tags: c

Minha função precisa achar a linha em que ocorre a primeira ocorrência de um vetor dentro de uma matriz e retornar sua linha. Porém sempre está retornando a linha errada, a minha lógica esta errada?

Minha função:

```
int busca( int mat[][MAX],int n, int m, int N, float vetor[])
{  
int i,j,k,aux;

for(k=0;k<N;k++)
{
    printf("Informe o valor do %d vetor:", k+1  ); // le o vetor
    scanf("%f",&vetor[k]);
}

for (i =0; i < n ;i ++)
{
    for ( j = 0; j < m ;j ++)
    {
        printf ("Digite mat [%d][%d]: ",i , j) ; //le a matriz
        scanf ("%d",&mat [i][j]) ;
    }
}

//aqui seria a logica pra achar o elemento igual
for(i=0; i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<m;j++)
    {
        if(mat[i][j] == vetor[k])
        {
            return i;

        }
    }
}

if (i>=0)  
printf("  A primeira ocorrencia do vetor eh na linha %d\n.",i-1 );
else
return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tua lógica pra achar o vetor tá incompleta, porque você precisa zerar a variável **k**, que foi utilizada anteriormente nessa parte do código:

```
for(k=0;k<N;k++)
{
    printf("Informe o valor do %d vetor:", k+1  ); // le o vetor
    scanf("%f",&vetor[k]);
}
```

Então, uma solução, utilizando sua lógica ainda, seria a seguinte:

```
// essa variável deve ser utilizada antes da repetição
int cont;

///aqui seria a logica pra achar o elemento igual
for(i=0; i<n;i++)
{
    cont=0;
    k = 0;

    for(j=0;j<m;j++, k++)
    {
        //essa condição serve para caso o "k" ultrapasse o tamanho
        // "N" do vetor, evitando acessar um índice do vetor que
        // não existe
        if(k>=N)
        {
            k=0;
        }

        if(mat[i][j] == vetor[k])
        {
            // aqui a variável conta quantos elementos do vetor 
            // são iguais a linha "i" da matriz
            cont++; 
        }
    }

    // se "cont" for igual a quantidade "N" de elementos do vetor
    // isso quer dizer que o programa encontrou a primeira ocorrência
    // do vetor na matriz 
    if(cont == N)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

A exibição do resultado também deve ser corrigida pra o seguinte:

```
    if (i>=0 && cont == N) 
        // Tem que ser utilizado "i" e não "i-1", pois caso o "i"
        // seja igual a zero, será exibido -1
        printf("  A primeira ocorrencia do vetor eh na linha %d\n.",i );
    else
        return -1;
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

A tua lógica está errada. Não testei o código mas o que a sua função faz é retornar a primeira linha que contém o último elemento do vetor. Uma boa alternativa seria fazer o seguinte:

```
//aqui seria a logica pra achar o elemento igual
for(i == 0; i < n; i++){
    if(!memcmp(mat[n], vector, sizeof(vector));
        return i;
}

return -1
```

A função `memcmp` compara dois blocos de código e retorna 0 se os blocos forem iguais.